# composite key associations in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 4 models in my rails app:

Classroom / Teacher / Pupil / Assignment

I need to have a:

n*n relationship between Classroom and Teacher
n*n relationship between Teacher and Pupil

For those two relations, that's ok as I'll create 2 migrations for the has_and_belongs_to_many .

For the Assignments model, I need to have it linked with the 3 previous models:

Assignments table should be like:
  - id
  - label
  - classroom_id
  - teacher_id
  - pupil_id

Is the following the best approach to modelize this last relationship ?

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: classroom
  belongs_to: teacher
  belongs_to: pupil
end

class classroom < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: assignments
end

class teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: assignments
end

class pupils < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: assignments
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider polymorphic association http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: assignable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Classroom < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignment, :as => :assignable
end
```

Comment: does this association enables to sometimes have only a Pupil linked to an Assignment, sometimes have the tuple (Pupil, Teacher) and also have the (Pupil, Teacher, Classroom) tuple linked to the Assignment ? Hmm... I'm not sure I'm clear, but in my view the Assignment should be linked to the tuple (where one or 2 fields could be empty).

Comment: can several records share the same Assignment ? Let's say I have Pupil with id:2, Classroom with id:5, can the Assignment with id:20 be linked to the tuple (2,5) ?